# spherical histogram for 3D object

Tags: image-processing, histograms, image3d, plotting

I want to develop  a shperical histogram for 3D object. Given a 3D object, I put it in a cylinder where its axis pass through the centroid of the object. The cylinder is sampled into a number N of control points. Than, for each a control point Pn, each point of the considered object is encoded in a spherical frame of reference centered  in Pn with dimensions `ρ` (from 0 to a suitable value), `θ` (form 0 to 180 degree) and `ϕ`(from 0 to 360 degree). Each polar coordinate is uniformly sampled into ten parts, obtaining a set of 1000 elements {(ρi, θj, ϕk) : 0 ≤ i , j , k ≤ 9}. This image illustrates the reference cylinder and some controls points.

```
 data3D={{607.587, 401.119, 1140}, {607.587, 481.119, 1100}, {607.587, 
      561.119, 1020}, {647.587, 361.119, 1140}, {647.587, 361.119, 
      1300}, {647.587, 401.119, 1180}, {647.587, 401.119, 1340}, {647.587,
       441.119, 1140}, {647.587, 481.119, 1020}, {647.587, 521.119, 
      980}, {647.587, 561.119, 980}, {647.587, 601.119, 980}, {647.587, 
      641.119, 980}, {687.587, 321.119, 1180}, {687.587, 361.119, 
      1060}, {687.587, 361.119, 1220}, {687.587, 361.119, 1380}, {687.587,
       401.119, 1140}, {687.587, 401.119, 1300}, {687.587, 441.119, 
      1100}, {687.587, 441.119, 1260}, {687.587, 481.119, 1060}, {687.587,
       481.119, 1220}, {687.587, 561.119, 1020}, {687.587, 601.119, 
      1020}, {687.587, 681.119, 940}, {727.587, 321.119, 1060}, {727.587, 
      321.119, 1220}, {727.587, 321.119, 1380}, {727.587, 361.119, 
      1100}, {727.587, 361.119, 1260}, {727.587, 361.119, 1420}, {727.587,
       401.119, 1020}, {727.587, 401.119, 1180}, {727.587, 401.119, 
      1340}, {727.587, 441.119, 1060}, {727.587, 441.119, 1220}, {727.587,
       441.119, 1380}, {727.587, 481.119, 1180}, {727.587, 481.119, 
      1340}, {727.587, 521.119, 1220}, {727.587, 721.119, 980}, {767.587, 
      281.119, 1220}, {767.587, 281.119, 1380}, {767.587, 321.119, 
      1180}, {767.587, 321.119, 1340}, {767.587, 361.119, 860}, {767.587, 
      361.119, 1020}, {767.587, 361.119, 1180}, {767.587, 361.119, 
      1340}, {767.587, 401.119, 740}, {767.587, 401.119, 900}, {767.587, 
      401.119, 1060}, {767.587, 401.119, 1220}, {767.587, 401.119, 
      1380}, {767.587, 441.119, 740}, {767.587, 441.119, 900}, {767.587, 
      441.119, 1060}, {767.587, 441.119, 1220}, {767.587, 441.119, 
      1380}, {767.587, 481.119, 820}, {767.587, 481.119, 980}, {767.587, 
      481.119, 1140}, {767.587, 481.119, 1300}, {767.587, 521.119, 
      1060}, {767.587, 521.119, 1220}, {767.587, 521.119, 1380}, {767.587,
       561.119, 1220}, {807.587, 241.119, 1180}, {807.587, 241.119, 
      1340}, {807.587, 281.119, 1180}, {807.587, 281.119, 1340}, {807.587,
       321.119, 980}, {807.587, 321.119, 1140}, {807.587, 321.119, 
      1300}, {807.587, 321.119, 1460}, {807.587, 361.119, 820}, {807.587, 
      361.119, 980}, {807.587, 361.119, 1140}, {807.587, 361.119, 
      1300}, {807.587, 361.119, 1460}, {807.587, 401.119, 620}, {807.587, 
      401.119, 780}, {807.587, 401.119, 940}, {807.587, 401.119, 
      1100}, {807.587, 401.119, 1260}, {807.587, 401.119, 1420}, {807.587,
       441.119, 580}, {807.587, 441.119, 740}, {807.587, 441.119, 
      900}, {807.587, 441.119, 1060}, {807.587, 441.119, 1220}, {807.587, 
      441.119, 1380}, {807.587, 441.119, 1580}, {807.587, 481.119, 
      660}, {807.587, 481.119, 820}, {807.587, 481.119, 980}, {807.587, 
      481.119, 1140}, {807.587, 481.119, 1300}, {807.587, 481.119, 
      1460}, {807.587, 481.119, 1700}, {807.587, 521.119, 1020}, {807.587,
       521.119, 1180}, {807.587, 521.119, 1340}, {807.587, 521.119, 
      1620}, {807.587, 561.119, 1060}, {807.587, 561.119, 1220}, {807.587,
       561.119, 1380}, {807.587, 601.119, 1220}, {847.587, 201.119, 
      1260}, {847.587, 241.119, 1140}, {847.587, 241.119, 1300}, {847.587,
       281.119, 1020}, {847.587, 281.119, 1180}, {847.587, 281.119, 
      1340}, {847.587, 321.119, 340}, {847.587, 321.119, 500}, {847.587, 
      321.119, 780}, {847.587, 321.119, 980}, {847.587, 321.119, 
      1140}, {847.587, 321.119, 1300}, {847.587, 321.119, 1460}, {847.587,
       361.119, 380}, {847.587, 361.119, 540}, {847.587, 361.119, 
      700}, {847.587, 361.119, 860}, {847.587, 361.119, 1020}, {847.587, 
      361.119, 1180}, {847.587, 361.119, 1340}, {847.587, 361.119, 
      1500}, {847.587, 401.119, 420}, {847.587, 401.119, 580}, {847.587, 
      401.119, 740}, {847.587, 401.119, 900}, {847.587, 401.119, 
      1060}, {847.587, 401.119, 1220}, {847.587, 401.119, 1380}, {847.587,
       401.119, 1540}, {847.587, 441.119, 140}, {847.587, 441.119, 
      300}, {847.587, 441.119, 460}, {847.587, 441.119, 620}, {847.587, 
      441.119, 780}, {847.587, 441.119, 940}, {847.587, 441.119, 
      1100}, {847.587, 441.119, 1260}, {847.587, 441.119, 1420}, {847.587,
       441.119, 1580}, {847.587, 441.119, 1740}, {847.587, 481.119, 
      620}, {847.587, 481.119, 780}, {847.587, 481.119, 940}, {847.587, 
      481.119, 1100}, {847.587, 481.119, 1260}, {847.587, 481.119, 
      1420}, {847.587, 481.119, 1580}, {847.587, 481.119, 1740}, {847.587,
       521.119, 820}, {847.587, 521.119, 980}, {847.587, 521.119, 
      1140}, {847.587, 521.119, 1300}, {847.587, 521.119, 1460}, {847.587,
       521.119, 1660}, {847.587, 561.119, 1020}, {847.587, 561.119, 
      1180}, {847.587, 561.119, 1340}, {847.587, 561.119, 1620}, {847.587,
       601.119, 1060}, {847.587, 601.119, 1220}, {847.587, 641.119, 
      1100}, {887.587, 201.119, 1100}, {887.587, 201.119, 1260}, {887.587,
       201.119, 1420}, {887.587, 241.119, 1140}, {887.587, 241.119, 
      1300}, {887.587, 241.119, 1460}, {887.587, 281.119, 380}, {887.587, 
      281.119, 860}, {887.587, 281.119, 1020}, {887.587, 281.119, 
      1180}, {887.587, 281.119, 1340}, {887.587, 321.119, 100}, {887.587, 
      321.119, 260}, {887.587, 321.119, 420}, {887.587, 321.119, 
      580}, {887.587, 321.119, 740}, {887.587, 321.119, 980}, {887.587, 
      321.119, 1140}, {887.587, 321.119, 1300}, {887.587, 321.119, 
      1460}, {887.587, 361.119, 180}, {887.587, 361.119, 340}, {887.587, 
      361.119, 500}, {887.587, 361.119, 660}, {887.587, 361.119, 
      900}, {887.587, 361.119, 1060}, {887.587, 361.119, 1220}, {887.587, 
      361.119, 1380}, {887.587, 361.119, 1540}, {887.587, 401.119, 
      300}, {887.587, 401.119, 460}, {887.587, 401.119, 620}, {887.587, 
      401.119, 780}, {887.587, 401.119, 980}, {887.587, 401.119, 
      1140}, {887.587, 401.119, 1300}, {887.587, 401.119, 1460}, {887.587,
       401.119, 1620}, {887.587, 441.119, 60}, {887.587, 441.119, 
      420}, {887.587, 441.119, 580}, {887.587, 441.119, 780}, {887.587, 
      441.119, 940}, {887.587, 441.119, 1100}, {887.587, 441.119, 
      1260}, {887.587, 441.119, 1420}, {887.587, 441.119, 1580}, {887.587,
       441.119, 1740}, {887.587, 481.119, 140}, {887.587, 481.119, 
      700}, {887.587, 481.119, 860}, {887.587, 481.119, 1020}, {887.587, 
      481.119, 1180}, {887.587, 481.119, 1340}, {887.587, 481.119, 
      1500}, {887.587, 481.119, 1660}, {887.587, 521.119, 100}, {887.587, 
      521.119, 820}, {887.587, 521.119, 980}, {887.587, 521.119, 
      1140}, {887.587, 521.119, 1300}, {887.587, 521.119, 1460}, {887.587,
       521.119, 1620}, {887.587, 561.119, 700}, {887.587, 561.119, 
      860}, {887.587, 561.119, 1020}, {887.587, 561.119, 1180}, {887.587, 
      561.119, 1340}, {887.587, 561.119, 1540}, {887.587, 561.119, 
      1700}, {887.587, 601.119, 1100}, {887.587, 601.119, 1260}, {887.587,
       641.119, 1060}, {927.587, 161.119, 1100}, {927.587, 161.119, 
      1260}, {927.587, 201.119, 1140}, {927.587, 201.119, 1300}, {927.587,
       241.119, 340}, {927.587, 241.119, 1060}, {927.587, 241.119, 
      1220}, {927.587, 241.119, 1380}, {927.587, 281.119, 140}, {927.587, 
      281.119, 300}, {927.587, 281.119, 900}, {927.587, 281.119, 
      1060}, {927.587, 281.119, 1220}, {927.587, 281.119, 1380}, {927.587,
       321.119, 60}, {927.587, 321.119, 220}, {927.587, 321.119, 
      380}, {927.587, 321.119, 580}, {927.587, 321.119, 980}, {927.587, 
      321.119, 1140}, {927.587, 321.119, 1300}, {927.587, 321.119, 
      1460}, {927.587, 361.119, 100}, {927.587, 361.119, 260}, {927.587, 
      361.119, 420}, {927.587, 361.119, 580}, {927.587, 361.119, 
      780}, {927.587, 361.119, 980}, {927.587, 361.119, 1140}, {927.587, 
      361.119, 1300}, {927.587, 361.119, 1460}, {927.587, 401.119, 
      100}, {927.587, 401.119, 340}, {927.587, 401.119, 500}, {927.587, 
      401.119, 700}, {927.587, 401.119, 900}, {927.587, 401.119, 
      1060}, {927.587, 401.119, 1220}, {927.587, 401.119, 1380}, {927.587,
       401.119, 1580}, {927.587, 441.119, 20}, {927.587, 441.119, 
      540}, {927.587, 441.119, 740}, {927.587, 441.119, 980}, {927.587, 
      441.119, 1140}, {927.587, 441.119, 1300}, {927.587, 441.119, 
      1460}, {927.587, 441.119, 1620}, {927.587, 481.119, 20}, {927.587, 
      481.119, 780}, {927.587, 481.119, 980}, {927.587, 481.119, 
      1140}, {927.587, 481.119, 1300}, {927.587, 481.119, 1460}, {927.587,
       481.119, 1620}, {927.587, 521.119, 60}, {927.587, 521.119, 
      820}, {927.587, 521.119, 980}, {927.587, 521.119, 1140}, {927.587, 
      521.119, 1300}, {927.587, 521.119, 1460}, {927.587, 521.119, 
      1620}, {927.587, 561.119, 700}, {927.587, 561.119, 860}, {927.587, 
      561.119, 1020}, {927.587, 561.119, 1180}, {927.587, 561.119, 
      1340}, {927.587, 561.119, 1620}, {927.587, 601.119, 740}, {927.587, 
      601.119, 900}, {927.587, 601.119, 1140}, {927.587, 601.119, 
      1300}, {967.587, 121.119, 1180}, {967.587, 161.119, 1140}, {967.587,
       201.119, 980}, {967.587, 201.119, 1140}, {967.587, 201.119, 
      1300}, {967.587, 241.119, 140}, {967.587, 241.119, 1180}, {967.587, 
      241.119, 1340}, {967.587, 281.119, 60}, {967.587, 281.119, 
      220}, {967.587, 281.119, 980}, {967.587, 281.119, 1140}, {967.587, 
      281.119, 1300}, {967.587, 321.119, 20}, {967.587, 321.119, 
      180}, {967.587, 321.119, 340}, {967.587, 321.119, 980}, {967.587, 
      321.119, 1140}, {967.587, 321.119, 1300}, {967.587, 321.119, 
      1460}, {967.587, 361.119, 140}, {967.587, 361.119, 300}, {967.587, 
      361.119, 460}, {967.587, 361.119, 620}, {967.587, 361.119, 
      1020}, {967.587, 361.119, 1180}, {967.587, 361.119, 1340}, {967.587,
       361.119, 1500}, {967.587, 401.119, 140}, {967.587, 401.119, 
      700}, {967.587, 401.119, 900}, {967.587, 401.119, 1060}, {967.587, 
      401.119, 1220}, {967.587, 401.119, 1380}, {967.587, 441.119, 
      20}, {967.587, 441.119, 780}, {967.587, 441.119, 980}, {967.587, 
      441.119, 1140}, {967.587, 441.119, 1300}, {967.587, 441.119, 
      1460}, {967.587, 481.119, 60}, {967.587, 481.119, 860}, {967.587, 
      481.119, 1060}, {967.587, 481.119, 1220}, {967.587, 481.119, 
      1380}, {967.587, 481.119, 1620}, {967.587, 521.119, 740}, {967.587, 
      521.119, 940}, {967.587, 521.119, 1100}, {967.587, 521.119, 
      1260}, {967.587, 521.119, 1420}, {967.587, 561.119, 620}, {967.587, 
      561.119, 780}, {967.587, 561.119, 1020}, {967.587, 561.119, 
      1180}, {967.587, 561.119, 1340}, {967.587, 601.119, 540}, {967.587, 
      601.119, 700}, {967.587, 601.119, 860}, {967.587, 641.119, 
      420}, {967.587, 641.119, 580}, {967.587, 641.119, 780}, {1007.59, 
      161.119, 980}, {1007.59, 161.119, 1180}, {1007.59, 201.119, 
      980}, {1007.59, 201.119, 1140}, {1007.59, 241.119, 820}, {1007.59, 
      241.119, 1020}, {1007.59, 241.119, 1220}, {1007.59, 241.119, 
      1380}, {1007.59, 281.119, 1060}, {1007.59, 281.119, 1220}, {1007.59,
       281.119, 1380}, {1007.59, 321.119, 100}, {1007.59, 321.119, 
      980}, {1007.59, 321.119, 1140}, {1007.59, 321.119, 1300}, {1007.59, 
      321.119, 1460}, {1007.59, 361.119, 140}, {1007.59, 361.119, 
      1020}, {1007.59, 361.119, 1180}, {1007.59, 361.119, 1340}, {1007.59,
       401.119, 20}, {1007.59, 401.119, 580}, {1007.59, 401.119, 
      780}, {1007.59, 401.119, 1020}, {1007.59, 401.119, 1180}, {1007.59, 
      401.119, 1340}, {1007.59, 401.119, 1500}, {1007.59, 441.119, 
      820}, {1007.59, 441.119, 1100}, {1007.59, 441.119, 1260}, {1007.59, 
      441.119, 1420}, {1007.59, 481.119, 700}, {1007.59, 481.119, 
      940}, {1007.59, 481.119, 1100}, {1007.59, 481.119, 1260}, {1007.59, 
      481.119, 1420}, {1007.59, 521.119, 660}, {1007.59, 521.119, 
      820}, {1007.59, 521.119, 1020}, {1007.59, 521.119, 1180}, {1007.59, 
      521.119, 1340}, {1007.59, 561.119, 540}, {1007.59, 561.119, 
      700}, {1007.59, 561.119, 900}, {1007.59, 601.119, 380}, {1007.59, 
      601.119, 540}, {1007.59, 601.119, 700}, {1007.59, 641.119, 
      220}, {1007.59, 641.119, 380}, {1007.59, 641.119, 540}, {1007.59, 
      641.119, 700}, {1007.59, 641.119, 860}, {1007.59, 681.119, 
      220}, {1007.59, 681.119, 380}, {1007.59, 681.119, 540}, {1007.59, 
      681.119, 820}, {1007.59, 721.119, 180}, {1007.59, 721.119, 
      340}, {1007.59, 761.119, 60}, {1007.59, 841.119, 60}, {1047.59, 
      201.119, 1100}, {1047.59, 241.119, 1060}, {1047.59, 241.119, 
      1220}, {1047.59, 281.119, 1060}, {1047.59, 281.119, 1300}, {1047.59,
       321.119, 1100}, {1047.59, 321.119, 1260}, {1047.59, 321.119, 
      1420}, {1047.59, 361.119, 1020}, {1047.59, 361.119, 1180}, {1047.59,
       361.119, 1340}, {1047.59, 401.119, 820}, {1047.59, 401.119, 
      1060}, {1047.59, 401.119, 1220}, {1047.59, 401.119, 1380}, {1047.59,
       441.119, 700}, {1047.59, 441.119, 860}, {1047.59, 441.119, 
      1100}, {1047.59, 441.119, 1260}, {1047.59, 441.119, 1420}, {1047.59,
       481.119, 700}, {1047.59, 481.119, 860}, {1047.59, 481.119, 
      1100}, {1047.59, 481.119, 1260}, {1047.59, 481.119, 1420}, {1047.59,
       521.119, 620}, {1047.59, 521.119, 780}, {1047.59, 521.119, 
      1020}, {1047.59, 521.119, 1180}, {1047.59, 561.119, 380}, {1047.59, 
      561.119, 540}, {1047.59, 561.119, 700}, {1047.59, 561.119, 
      860}, {1047.59, 601.119, 380}, {1047.59, 601.119, 540}, {1047.59, 
      601.119, 700}, {1047.59, 601.119, 860}, {1047.59, 641.119, 
      180}, {1047.59, 641.119, 340}, {1047.59, 641.119, 500}, {1047.59, 
      641.119, 660}, {1047.59, 681.119, 60}, {1047.59, 681.119, 
      220}, {1047.59, 681.119, 380}, {1047.59, 681.119, 540}, {1047.59, 
      721.119, 100}, {1047.59, 721.119, 260}, {1047.59, 721.119, 
      420}, {1047.59, 761.119, 140}, {1047.59, 801.119, 20}, {1047.59, 
      841.119, 20}, {1047.59, 881.119, 60}}


    {cx, cy, cz} = Round[Mean[data3D]];
    p1 = {cx, cy + 500, 880};
    p2 = {cx, cy - 500, 880};
    p3 = {cx + 500, cy, 880};
    p4 = {cx - 500, cy, 880};
    p5 = {cx + 354, cy + 354, 880};
    p6 = {cx - 354, cy - 354, 880};
    p7 = {cx + 354, cy - 354, 880};
    p8 = {cx - 354, cy + 354, 880};
    p9 = {cx + 468, cy + 177, 880};
    p10 = {cx - 468, cy + 177, 880};
    p11 = {cx + 468, cy - 177, 880};
    p12 = {cx - 468, cy - 177, 880};
    p13 = {cx + 177, cy + 468, 880};
    p14 = {cx + 177, cy - 468, 880};
    p15 = {cx - 177, cy + 468, 880};
    p16 = {cx - 177, cy - 468, 880};
Show[Graphics3D[{PointSize[.015], Blue, Point[#] & /@ data3D}], 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], 
   Cylinder[{{cx, cy, 880}, {cx, cy, 881}}, 500]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p1]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p2]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p3]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p4]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p1]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p5]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p6]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p7]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p8]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p9]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p10]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p11]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p12]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p13]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p14]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p15]}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Red, Point[p16]}]]
```

Now I need to get the spherical histogram corresponding to each control point Pn.

[image]

I start to code this using these 3 functions but I am not sure about the result because I get similar histograms for the different control points that having 0 values between 300 and 700.

1) convert data3D in spherical coordinate corresponding to each control points.
2) compute number of points that laying on each bins (ρi, θj, ϕk).
 (this function is to convert from cartesian to spherical coordinates)

```
cartesian2spherical[{x0_, y0_, z0_}, {x_, y_, z_}] := 
 Module[{r, θ, ϕ}, (
   (*0<=θ≤π,
   0≤ϕ≤2π*)

   r = N[Norm[{x, y, z} - {x0, y0, z0}]];
   θ = Mod[N[ArcCos[(z - z0)/r]/Degree] + 180, 180];
   If[(x - x0) == 0, ϕ = 
     Mod[N[ArcTan[(y - y0)/(0.00000000000000000000000001)]/Degree] + 
       360, 360], ϕ = 
     Mod[N[ArcTan[(y - y0)/(x - x0)]/Degree] + 360, 360]];
   {r, θ, ϕ}

   )]

newBinCounts[angles_, bins_] := Module[{hist, sectorIndex}, (
   hist = BinCounts[angles, {bins}];
   sectorIndex = 
    Table[Flatten[
      Union[Position[angles, #] & /@ 
        Select[angles, bins[[i]] <= # < bins[[i + 1]] &]]], {i, 1, 
      Length[bins] - 1}];
   sectorIndex
   )]
```

(*histogram corresponding to each control point*)

```
histogramPoint[p_, voxelset_] := 
 Module[{coordinates, anglesϕ, anglesθ, raduis, 
   binsθ, binsϕ, binsr, sectorIndexϕ, sectorIndexr, 
   listofraduis, listofθ, hist, histogram, maxraduis}, (
   (*Convertir les points de systeme cartisien vers le systeme \
spherique*)
   coordinates = cartesian2spherical[p, #] & /@ voxelset;
   anglesϕ = coordinates[[All, 3]];
   anglesθ = coordinates[[All, 2]];
   raduis = coordinates[[All, 1]];
   maxraduis = Round[Max[raduis]];
   (*pick bins for each parameters θ, ϕ,r*)

   binsϕ = Range[0, 360, 360/10];
   binsθ = Range[0, 180, 180/10];
   binsr = Range[0, 1900, 1900/10];
   (*Now for each ϕ for each θ for each r calculate the \
number of voxel in the correspondant volume*)
   (*1. return the \
histogram according to ϕ and the index of each voxel laying in \
each sector ϕ*)

   sectorIndexϕ = newBinCounts[anglesϕ, binsϕ];
   (*recuperate raduis laying on each ϕ*)

   listofraduis = raduis[[#]] & /@ sectorIndexϕ;
   (*for each list of raduis laying on each ϕ, 
   we calculate index laying on each r*)

   sectorIndexr = newBinCounts[#, binsr] & /@ listofraduis;
   (*for each list of raduis on each ϕ,
   we calculate the index laying on each θ*)

   listofθ = 
    anglesθ[[#]] & /@ Flatten[sectorIndexr, 1];
   hist = BinCounts[#, {binsθ}] & /@ listofθ;
   histogram = Flatten[hist /. {} -> ConstantArray[0, 10]])]

listOfhistograms1 = 
  histogramPoint[#, data3D] & /@ {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, 
    p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16};

totalhist = Total[listOfhistograms1];

normalizedhistogram1 = N[totalhist/Max[totalhist]]

ListPlot[normalizedhistogram1, Joined -> True, DataRange -> All, 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2, AxesOrigin -> 0, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 1000, 100], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: any comment on my code?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can use `SectorChart` for your *spherical histogram*.

This can be done by binning the points in the x-y plane by the archs that each control point covers. I've done this by

1. Take the centre of the data in the x-y plane and shift the points to
   the origin.
2. Convert the points to polar coordinates. I make an adjustment for negative angles.
3. Bin the points by the control point archs. Here I just used 16 equally spaced control points.
4. Plot with `SectorChart`

.

```
centre = Mean /@ Transpose@data3D[[All, 1 ;; 2]];

binValues = 
 HistogramList[
  ToPolarCoordinates[
   Thread[Subtract[centre, #]] & /@ 
    data3D[[All, 1 ;; 2]]][[All,2]
  ] /. {v_?Negative -> 2 π + v},
  {Range[0, 2 \[Pi], 2 π / 16]}];

SectorChart[Transpose@{ConstantArray[1, 16], binValues[[2]]},
 PolarAxes -> True,
 PolarGridLines -> Automatic,
 PolarTicks -> {
   Transpose@{Rest@Range[0, 2 π, 2 π / 16],
     StringJoin["P", #] & /@ IntegerString[Range[16]]}
   , Automatic}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.